# Passar variáveis na .css() do Jquery

Tags: jquery, variáveis, propriedade

Estou tendo problemas com o seguinte código:

```
//Desktop = D
var posicaoMenuD = $('#desktop-menu').position().top();
$(document).scroll(function(){//Alscutador de scroll da página
    var posicaoScrollD = $(document).scrollTop(); //Obtém o scroll atual (posição)
    if (posicaoMenuD < posicaoScrollD){
        $("#desktop-menu").css('top':$("#desktop-top-menu").height().val());
    }
});
```

Estou tentando passar variáveis na propriedade `.css()` do `jquery`, porém, sem sucesso, tentei declarando a variável antes também, porém da mesma forma não funcionou, no `console`, a mensagem:

```
scrolls-home.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Gostaria de saber como posso resolver tal problema, e se possível, uma explicação acompanhada do código, pois quero entender o que se passa.

Comment: tente `$("#desktop-menu").css('top', $("#desktop-top-menu").height());`

Comment: aqui deu o mesmo erro :(

Comment: Okay, então tente obter um `console.log($("#desktop-top-menu").height().val()));` e depois disso, tente definir um css predefinido, assim: `$("#desktop-menu").css('top', '30px');`. Não esqueça de adicionar a estrutura de medida ao final da variável também

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente substituir esta linha:

```
$("#desktop-menu").css('top':$("#desktop-top-menu").height().val());
```

por esta:

```
$("#desktop-menu").css('top', $("#desktop-top-menu").height() + 'px');
```

De acordo com o seu erro, este é um problema de sintaxe. Para setar um valor, o método [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value) recebe dois parâmetros. O primeiro é o atributo que você deseja modificar, e o segundo, o valor.

Quando você for modificar valores como `top`, `margin`, `padding`, não esqueça de fornecer o valor junto com a medida, como se fosse escrever no próprio css.

**EDITADO**

Editado para inserir aqui o fiddle criado pelo @LeonardoRodrigues com um demo: https://jsfiddle.net/leonardorodrigues/8ptLbgnt/

Comment: Eu havia criado um pequeno exemplo para mostrar, se quiser implementar em sua resposta: https://jsfiddle.net/leonardorodrigues/8ptLbgnt/

Comment: @LeonardoRodrigues Ótimo, adicionado!

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos :3